# How can I draw a QGraphicsRectItem that is (properly) movable by clicking on a QGraphicsView/QGraphicsScene canvas?

Tags: python, pyqt5

I want to draw rectangles on a QGrahicsView/QGrahicsScene canvas by subclassing QGraphicsRectItem. The rectangles should appear just by clicking on the canvas. After drawing the rectangles, the rectangles should be movable just by dragging them around.

1. I subclassed `QGraphicsRectItem` to draw my custom rectangle and set it as movable via `.setFlags(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsMovable)`.
2. I subclassed `QGraphicsView` and implemented `mousePressEvent()` such that it instantiates my custom `QGraphicsRectItem` class with the coordinates of the clicked position.

I expect to be able to draw rectangles on the canvas just by clicking on it. Furthermore, I want to be able to move the rectangles around. I can do both, but only drawing the rectangles by clicking on the canvas works properly. Grabbing the rectangles to move them around is next to impossible because I have to grab the exact pixel (actually, it's the top-left intersection between the rectangle lines) to move the rectangles around.

I can grab a rectangle properly by clicking anywhere on its body if I do not spawn a rectangle by reimplementing `mousePressEvent()` but instead just instantiate it in the class's initiator. But then I lose the ability to spawn rectangles just by clicking on the canvas.

Is there a possibility to keep the functionality of spawning rectangles just by clicking on the canvas while also being able to easily move the rectangles around?

This is what I have got so far:

```python
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtGui import QBrush, QMouseEvent, QPen
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (
    QApplication,
    QGraphicsItem,
    QGraphicsRectItem,
    QGraphicsScene,
    QGraphicsView,
)


class RectangleItem(QGraphicsRectItem):
    def __init__(self, x: float, y: float, width: float, height: float):
        super().__init__(x, y, width, height)

        self.setBrush(QBrush(Qt.red))
        self.setPen(QPen(Qt.black, 20))

        self.setFlags(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsMovable | QGraphicsItem.ItemIsSelectable)


class GraphicsView(QGraphicsView):
    def __init__(self, scene: QGraphicsScene):
        super().__init__(scene)

        # rectangle = RectangleItem(0, 0, 100, 100)
        # self.scene().addItem(rectangle)

    def mousePressEvent(self, event: QMouseEvent):
        scene_position = self.mapToScene(event.pos())
        rectangle = RectangleItem(scene_position.x(), scene_position.y(), 100, 100)
        self.scene().addItem(rectangle)


app = QApplication([])
scene = QGraphicsScene()
view = GraphicsView(scene)
view.show()
app.exec()
```

Comment: Sounds to me like you need to check ```GraphicsView.items()``` to see if you are near the border of an item. If you are, call ```super().mousePressEvent()``` instead of adding a new one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the hint of [@Homer521](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17167312/homer512) and a bit of research, I found a solution:

Instead of my above reimplementation of `mousePressEvent`, I used

```python
def mousePressEvent(self, event: QMouseEvent):
    item = self.itemAt(event.pos())
    if item:
        return super().mousePressEvent(event)
    scene_position = self.mapToScene(event.pos())
    rectangle = RectangleItem(scene_position.x(), scene_position.y(), 100, 100)
    self.scene().addItem(rectangle)
    return None
```

Thsi first checks whether a `QGraphicsItem` (or a subclass of it) exists at the position you clicked at. If it does, it just returns to the original implementation of `mousePressEvent` which allows you to use all the mouse interaction related functionality that a `QGraphicsItem` comes with by default. If there is no item at that position, it just runs the code responsible for generating the function.

Bonus: if you want to be able to use context menus on your `QGraphicsItems`, wrap the above definition of `mousePressEvent` in a `if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:` so that it is only executed when you left click.